# Weird problem on STM32 ADC with Interleaved Mode

Tags: adc, stm32, c, embedded, arm

I am sampling a signal on the STM32F3 Discovery board (stm32f303vct6) with two ADCs working in interleaved mode. It works great with a 200kHz 1V sine wave. But when I apply 10kHz 100mV sine wave, I see some interesting patterns. ADCs seem to convert all the voltage levels in a specific gap into a single number. It is like sampling in lower resolution. When you see the images below it will be clear.

I have also tried to run ADCs in independent mode and triggered them with 2 synchronized timers but still, the pattern is there.
I don't encounter this problem when only one ADC is sampling.

Images:

1 [Sampled signal with interleaved mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBh5J.png)

2 [Samples of one of the ADCs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxhe7.png)

Sample code:

````
#include "stm32f30x.h"
//#define DUALDMA

void sysinit();
void clockconfig();
void delay(int d);
void adcinit();
void dmainit();
void dualdmainit();

int main(){
    sysinit();
    clockconfig();

    #ifdef DUALDMA
    dualdmainit();
    #else
    dmainit();
    #endif

    adcinit();

    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOEEN; // GPIOE enable
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN; // GPIOA enable
    GPIOE->MODER = 0x55555555; // GPIOE -> output 
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x0000FFFF;// GPIOA -> analog

    // Reset SRAM memory area
    for(int i = 0;i<1024*4;i+=4){
        *((uint32_t*)(0x20000800+i)) = 0;
    }

    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTART;
    while(1);
}

void delay(int d){
    // Dummy delay
    int l = d*1000;
    for(int i = 0;i<l;i++);
}


void adcinit(){

    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_ADC12EN; // Enable ADC clock
    RCC->CFGR2 |= RCC_CFGR2_ADCPRE12_4;// ADC clock prescaler = 1


    ADC1->CFGR |=  ADC_CFGR_CONT; // Continous mode
    ADC1->SQR1  |= ADC_SQR1_SQ1_0 ; // ch 1

    ADC2->SQR1  |= ADC_SQR1_SQ1_0 ; // ch 1

    ADC1_2->CCR |= ADC12_CCR_DELAY_2 ; // Delay = 4 (5 Cycles)
    #ifndef DUALDMA
    ADC1_2->CCR |= ADC12_CCR_MDMA_1; // If single DMA is selected, configure MDMA bits for 12 bits
    #else
    ADC1->CFGR |=  ADC_CFGR_DMAEN;
    ADC2->CFGR |=  ADC_CFGR_DMAEN;
    #endif
    ADC1_2->CCR |= ADC12_CCR_MULTI_2 | ADC12_CCR_MULTI_1 | ADC12_CCR_MULTI_0; // Interleaved mode
    //ADC1_2->CCR |= ADC12_CCR_CKMODE_0; // Does not seem to change anything

    ADC1->CR &= ~(ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_1 | ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_0); // Enable VREG
    ADC1->CR |=  ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_0;
    delay(500);

    ADC2->CR &= ~(ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_1 | ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_0);
    ADC2->CR |=  ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_0;
    delay(500);

    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;
    while( (ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRD) == 0 );
    while( (ADC2->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRD) == 0 );

}

void dmainit(){
    // DMA config for Single DMA, 32 bits
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN;

    DMA1_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t)&ADC1_2->CDR;
    DMA1_Channel1->CMAR = 0x20000800;
    DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR = 1024;
    DMA1_Channel1->CCR = DMA_CCR_EN | DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_MSIZE_1 | DMA_CCR_PSIZE_1;

}

void dualdmainit(){
    // DMA config for DUAL DMA, 16bits
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN; // DMA1 Enable
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA2EN; // DMA2 Enable

    DMA1_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t)&ADC1->DR;
    DMA1_Channel1->CMAR = 0x20000800;
    DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR = 1024;
    DMA1_Channel1->CCR = DMA_CCR_EN | DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_MSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR_PSIZE_0;

    DMA2_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t)&ADC2->DR;
    DMA2_Channel1->CMAR = 0x20000800+1024*2;
    DMA2_Channel1->CNDTR = 1024;
    DMA2_Channel1->CCR = DMA_CCR_EN | DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_MSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR_PSIZE_0;

}

void clockconfig(){
    // External oscillator (HSE): 8MHz 
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSEON; // Enable HSE
    while( (RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY) == 0 );

    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL9; // PLL MUL = x9
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV2; // APB1 Prescaler = 2
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC; // PLL source = HSE

    FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_1; // Two wait states

    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;  // Enable and wait PLL
    while( (RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) == 0 );

    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL; // Select PLL as system clock

}
void sysinit(){

    //STM32F303 reset state
    /* Reset the RCC clock configuration to the default reset state ------------*/
  /* Set HSION bit */
  RCC->CR |= 0x00000001U;
  /* Reset CFGR register */
  RCC->CFGR &= 0xF87FC00CU;
  /* Reset HSEON, CSSON and PLLON bits */
  RCC->CR &= 0xFEF6FFFFU;
  /* Reset HSEBYP bit */
  RCC->CR &= 0xFFFBFFFFU;
  /* Reset PLLSRC, PLLXTPRE, PLLMUL and USBPRE bits */
  RCC->CFGR &= 0xFF80FFFFU;
  /* Reset PREDIV1[3:0] bits */
  RCC->CFGR2 &= 0xFFFFFFF0U;
  /* Reset USARTSW[1:0], I2CSW and TIMs bits */
  RCC->CFGR3 &= 0xFF00FCCCU;
  /* Disable all interrupts */
  RCC->CIR = 0x00000000U;
  SCB->VTOR = 0x08000000; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal FLASH */

}
```
````

Comment: The schematics is more important than the source code

Comment: _I don't encounter this problem when only one adc is sampling_. But you get another problem, it looks like you are missing samples and the graph program draws a straight horizontal line.

Comment: @pipe i can sample the signal correctly when i use single adc so i don't think there is a problem with the schematic. And the samples here are obtained on STM32F3 Discovery board.

Comment: @SteveG I think there is a misunderstanding here. Both graphs have the same signal. First graph shows the combined samples, all the data, secnod graph shows half of the data (sampled by one adc but still in interleaved mode). When i turn off the second adc and run first ADC in independent mode, those horizontal lines disappear.

Comment: @SteveG Well i thought i was missing some samples but that is not the case. When i apply DC signal, ADC still samples, I see a line that has noise, small variations just as expected. But at specific voltage levels i see one straight line. no noise, no variations. Lets say all the samples are converted into hex value 0x083F. I dont see any value between 0x0840-0x0850 And this behaviour is very consistent.

Comment: Ok, but if the internal MUX keeps switching in and out capacitors to feed your signal to each internal ADC in turn, this may affect the signal. It doesn't happen when you're not MUXing stuff. The devboard doesn't seem to buffer anything. We don't know what you connected to it and it's easier if you just explain your setup from the beginning instead of everyone here asking "what's your source impedance", "which pins are you using", etc

Comment: @pipe I got your point. All the problematic samples end with 0x3F and 0xBF, that is why I thought I should prioritize the code.